# How can order place for multiple product from custom page after select multiple qty in magento?

Tags: php, magento, product

I created a custom page, displaying all product with qty button. Here we can choose multiple products. After that i want to order place of all selected products. How can i place order for multiple product? Is any plugin is available in magento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also in need of same functionality, will ended up this by using my own script instead of any plugin. Below is the complete code of placing order programatically. Hope this helps.

```
<?php
    $transaction = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction');
    $increment_ids = array();
    if ($orderData) {

        try {

            $reservedOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getEntityType('order')->fetchNewIncrementId($store_id);
            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
                ->setIncrementId($reservedOrderId)
                ->setStoreId($store_id)
                ->setQuoteId(0)
                ->setGlobal_currency_code('USD')
                ->setBase_currency_code('USD')
                ->setStore_currency_code('USD')
                ->setOrder_currency_code('USD');
                //saving customer
                $order->setCustomer_email($orderData['email'])
                ->setCustomerFirstname($orderData['firstname'])
                ->setCustomerLastname($orderData['lastname'])
                ->setCustomerGroupId(1)
                ->setCustomer_is_guest(1);


                $regionModel = Mage::getModel('directory/region')->loadByCode("CA", 'US');


                $shippingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')
                ->setStoreId($storeId)
                ->setAddressType(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::TYPE_SHIPPING)
                ->setFirstname($orderData['firstname'])
                ->setLastname($orderData['lastname'])
                ->setStreet($orderData['shipping']['line'])
                ->setCity($orderData['shipping']['city'])
                ->setRegion($orderData['shipping']['region'])
                ->setRegionId($regionModel->getId())
                ->setCountry_id('US')
                ->setPostcode($orderData['shipping']['postcode'])
                ->setTelephone($orderData['shipping']['telephone']);

                $order->setShippingAddress($shippingAddress)
                ->setShipping_method($orderData['shipping_method'])
                ->setShippingDescription($orderData['shipping_description']);

                //get region code
                $regionModel = Mage::getModel('directory/region')->loadByCode($orderData['billing']['region'], 'US');

                // set Billing Address            
                $billingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')
                ->setStoreId($storeId)
                ->setAddressType(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::TYPE_SHIPPING)
                ->setFirstname($orderData['firstname'])
                ->setLastname($orderData['lastname'])
                ->setStreet($orderData['billing']['line'])
                ->setCity($orderData['billing']['city'])
                ->setRegion($regionModel->getName())
                ->setRegionId($regionModel->getId())
                ->setCountry_id('US')
                ->setPostcode($orderData['billing']['postcode'])
                ->setTelephone($orderData['billing']['telephone']);
                $order->setBillingAddress($billingAddress);


                //save products
                $subTotal = 0;
                $productPrice=0;
                $qtyTotal=0;
                foreach ($orderData['items'] as $key=>$product) {
                    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($key);
                    $rowTotal = $_product->getPrice() * $product;
                    $orderItem = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')
                    ->setStoreId($storeId)
                    ->setQuoteItemId(0)
                    ->setQuoteParentItemId(NULL)
                    ->setProductId($key)
                    ->setProductType($_product->getTypeId())
                    ->setQtyBackordered(NULL)
                    ->setTotalQtyOrdered($product)
                    ->setQtyOrdered($product)
                    ->setName($_product->getName())
                    ->setSku($_product->getSku())
                    ->setPrice(($_product->getPrice()))
                    ->setBasePrice($_product->getPrice())
                    ->setOriginalPrice($_product->getPrice())
                    ->setRowTotal($rowTotal)
                    ->setBaseRowTotal($rowTotal);

                    $qtyTotal += $product;
                    $subTotal += $rowTotal;
                    $order->addItem($orderItem);
                }

                $grandTotal = ($subTotal+$orderData['shipping_charge'])-$orderData['discount'];


                $orderPayment = Mage::getModel('sales/order_payment')
                ->setStoreId($store_id)
                ->setCustomerPaymentId(0)
                ->setMethod('purchaseorder')
                ->setPo_number($reservedOrderId);
                $order->setPayment($orderPayment);


                //date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
                $order->setSubtotal($subTotal)
                ->setState('processing')
                ->setStatus('processing')
                ->setCouponCode($orderData['coupon'])
                ->setBaseDiscountAmount($orderData['discount'])
                ->setBaseGrandTotal($grandTotal)
                ->setBaseSubtotal($subTotal)
                ->setBaseTotalInvoiced($grandTotal)
                ->setBaseTotalQtyOrdered($qtyTotal)
                ->setDiscountAmount($orderData['discount'])
                ->setGrandTotal($grandTotal)
                ->setSubtotal($subTotal)
                ->setTotalQtyOrdered($qtyTotal)
                ->setBaseTotalDue($grandTotal)
                    //->setCreatedAt(date('Y-m-d'))
                    //->setUpdatedAt(date('Y-m-d'))
                ->setTotalItemCount($order_detail['qty'])
                ->setShippingAmount($orderData['shipping_charge'])
                ->setBaseShippingAmount($orderData['shipping_charge']);

                $transaction->addObject($order);
                $transaction->addCommitCallback(array($order, 'place'));
                $transaction->addCommitCallback(array($order, 'save'));
                $transaction->save();
                $order_data = $order->getData();
                $order_id = $order_data['increment_id'];


                $order->sendNewOrderEmail();


        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $finalresult=array('exception',$e->getMessage());           
        }
    }
```